# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 4 path $.SUCCESS

Tags: java, android, json, post, retrofit

I made a post request method with Retrofit2 but I encountered this problem on my response.

```
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 4 path $.SUCCESS
```

The response should be

```
{
"SUCCESS" :
{
"200" : "access granted",
"ra" : "approved",
"la" : "approved",
"ch" : "approved"
}
}
```

I uses this code for the post request

```
@POST("login")
Call<Post> createPost(@Body Post post);
```

And for the POJO class

```
public class Post {

    private String anthony;
    private String SUCCESS;

    public Post(String name) {
        this.anthony = name;
    }

    public String getSUCCESS() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

For the method I use the following code

```
private void createPost() {
        Post post = new Post("mypassword");
        Call<Post> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createPost(post);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                Post postResponse = response.body();
                String content = "";
                content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
                content += "S" + postResponse.getSUCCESS();
                textViewResult.setText(content);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? I expected to get the response inside the "SUCCESS" json object.

Comment: `private String SUCCESS;` does not match the data `"SUCCESS" : { "200" : "acc ...`

Comment: Any clue for me to get the response? @luk2302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect SUCCESS to be an object in your wanted response but you have defined it as a String in your Post class. You should use an object for SUCCESS instead.

```
public class Post {

    private String anthony;
    private PostSuccess SUCCESS;

    public Post(String name) {
        this.anthony = name;
    }

    public PostSuccess getSUCCESS() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

public class PostSuccess {
    @JsonProperty("200")
    private String _200;
    private String ra;
    private String la;
    private String ch;
}
```

Comment: Where do I get the @JsonProperty from?

Comment: It is from [Jackson Java library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You don't need it if you can avoid an attribute called "200" because that is no valid Java identifier.

Comment: After I removed the @JsonProperty and the "200" response, I get Post$PostSuccess@2f5769f on my getSuccess response. This is very confusing.

Comment: You should get familiar with Java basics. Printing post.getSuccess() will return the toString() result of PostSuccess (which is a default). You could override toString() of PostSuccess or make the print more specific (e.g. post.getSuccess().getRa(), don't forget the getters in PostSuccess)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot man. After I tried it, it finally works!!!!